# Ejecutar php version especifica linea comandos

Tags: php, laravel, centos

Tengo virtualmin instalado y un sitio con laravel 5.8, laravel corre bien con php 7.2, el sitio no tiene problema, pero cuando ejecuto un comando desde la linea de comandos, la ejecucion se hace con php 5.6
ejemplo **php artisan view:clear**  pero lo hace con php 5.6 y debe hacerlo con php7.2
Tengo centos 7, la pregunta es como corro el comando desde la linea de comandos con php7.2, el php7.2 lo tengo en **/etc/opt/rh/rh-php72** o como desabilito php 5.6 para que siempre que yo ejecute **php artisan view:clear** siempre corra con php7.2

Comment: Con el comando: scl enable rh-php72 bash Puedes ver más en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377847/set-default-version-of-php-in-centos-7

Comment: si no mal recuerdo, en el virtualmin le puedes decir cuál es la versión de php por defecto del dominio en donde estés, después de que hagas eso, reinicia apache

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias ahora esta funcionando

```
scl enable rh-php72 bash
```